# Request user consent for iOS App using Matomo analytics

Tags: ios, swift, matomo, app-transport-security

Im using Matomo for tracking user's page visits. Things that I'm getting is userId, and pages which user visited nothing more. Do I still need to request for consent? Im not sharing user data with any other apps.

Answer (score 1):

You are close.  Two caveats:

1. Matomo will store the URL. If you send GET requests with http there can be Names and personal information in the stored URL
2. I am assuming you are anonymizing IP addresses? Matomo allows partial anonymization or full anonymization.  This removes Geo data.

Check those two things and you are probably good.

Depending on whether you are staying compliant in EU or a specific EU country, interperetation of GDPR and PII (not identical) will vary a little.  Matomo has some guides for checking config settings for all of these in Matomo:

CNIL https://matomo.org/blog/2021/10/matomo-exempt-from-tracking-consent-in-france/
GDPR https://matomo.org/gdpr-analytics/
PII https://matomo.org/blog/2018/04/how-to-not-process-any-personal-data-with-matomo-and-what-it-means-for-you/

These are helpful for confirming which settings to apply and whether to modify the default settings.